# Get the name of the Kafka topic from a consumed message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

1. I am listening to multiple Kafka topics using regex pattern
2. The name of the topics for eg **worker_123_456_topic**,
   **worker_789_10112_topic** etc
3. I would like to grab **123_456** and **789_10112**
4. Hence is there anyway to know the name of the topic from the message consumed?

Any leads are much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring-Kafka API, in the Kafka message you should have an header called "RECEIVED_TOPIC" that contains the information you are looking for.

Check out this link:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/290

Answer (score 0):

Though other answers are correct, just explaining a little bit further :

Lets say, your key value pair is of type `String, String` then :

```
ConsumerRecords<String,String> recs = kafkaConsumer.poll();

Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> itr= recs.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
   String topicName = itr.next().topic(); 
    //then do split operation with topic name.
}
```

Comment: Why an iterator? Could use `for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> r : recs)`

Answer (score -1):

From the Java API, you can access [`ConsumerRecord.topic()`](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#topic()) regardless of how you are subscribing to the data.

> I would like to grab 123_456 and 789_10112

Given the string of the topic, use `substring` or `split("_", 1)` methods